# How to control materials falloff type from perpendicular/parallel to fresnel using nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I used to create falloff maps in 3dsmax quickly and easy. Now I would like to be able to do the same thing in blender.

Currently I am using Toggle diffuse ramp operation in blender, but it only allows the most simple falloff type. I need more control over specific falloff parameters like Mix Curve and Falloff Type (e.g. perpendicular/parallel or fresnel) from 3dsmax.

Any ideas how to achieve the result with nodes or without?

Comment: I know it's almost 4 years since this was posted, but there are still no acceptable solutions or answers to this. I really need this feature in blender myself.

Comment: Can you feed a linear gradient to an RGB Curves node and generate an arbitrary curve that way?